# combination a of 6a +9b+20c =n when n is range (0, 100)

Tags: python-2.7

I want to write a program sort like solving Diophantine Equation:

1. That is able to identify any number from 0 to 100 that is exactly with combination of 6a+9b+20C, when a, b, c are all non-negative integer between 0 to 10.
2. And also I want to write a program that is able to identify any number from 0 to 100 that is not exactly with combination of 6a+9b+20C.

I try with following with problem 2:

```
for num in range(0, 100):
    prime = True
    for i in range(3, 20, 3):
        if (num%i==0):
            prime=False
    if prime:
        print 'Largest number that cannot be bought in exact quantity', num
```

I can only get as far as this.

Comment: Sorry, python program, I just learn python, I am confuse how to write it so it will get what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function will give you a dictionary output which will contain all the numbers that are not the combination and the number which is the combination of your equation :-

```
def inputNo( a, b, c ):
    result = {"isComb":[], "notComb":[]}
    for i in range(1,100):
        if ((6*a)+(9*b)+(20*c) == i ):
            result['isComb'].append(i)
        else:
            result['notComb'].append(i)

    return result
```